# How to make a dropdown and date selected by refreshing the page in angular8 dynamic forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular7, angular8

Hi I am working on Angular Dynamic forms

Here is the code so far I tried:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nh46j9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

So, now I want the date should be pre-filled to `today's date` and the dropdown should be `california` and when I change the values then it should also change?

Any idea will be thankful?TIA.

Answer (score 1):

For date input you can do something like this:

app.component.ts

```
date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

app.component.html

```
<input type="date" name="date{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="date">
```

For dropdown you can do something like this:
clear the constructor function and push default object in districtArr outside constructor
app.component.ts

```
name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  districArr: any = [
    { id: 1, name: "california" },
    { id: 2, name: "texas" },
    { id: 3, name: "ohio" },
    { id: 4, name: "Washington" }
  ];
  city = this.districArr[0].name;
  date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  public datapush: any = [
    {
      date: this.date,
      district: this.city
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  add() {
    this.datapush.push({
      date: this.date,
      district: this.city
    });
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<option *ngFor="let dist of districArr" [value]="dist.id"
                                    [ngValue]="dist.name">{{dist.name}}</option>
```

You can do this with FormArray tho. It will be a lot easier

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hlvzjn)

Comment: This is not working as i click on new form again its reflecting that value of date.Could you make it through stackblitz?

Comment: @Stephenandrew here you go: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hlvzjn?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I also updated it slightly

Comment: i dont want the dates to show current dates it also should dynamically change as i add new coloumns. But by default, it should show todays date.

Comment: What if i want the `districArr` coming from API then  i have to load the dropdown values on refresh right?